# How to build GMP for intel i5 & AMD phenom

Tags: cygwin, cpu, gmp

I am trying to build GMP for an intel i5 cpu and an AMD phenom 1100T, neither being the same cpu as in my current computer. However, I'm not sure what build options to use. I have also read about lipo, and wondered what it meant. Could anyone give me an insight of how to do this? I'm using cygwin and GMP 6.0.0. I would also like to compile the c++ wrapper.

The reason I want to do this is because my program crashes on other computers when trying to execute certain functions, throwing an illegal instruction exception. I have talked to a fellow programmer who suggested it might be because of it being cpu dependent, which I thought made sense.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `configure` tool optimizes the GMP library for the current processor. The preferred solution is to use the `--enable-fat` option when you run `configure`. That option instructs GMP to include multiple versions of each function that is optimized for the each specific supported CPU.